# Underline individual items on navigation wordpress

Tags: css, navigation, styling, elementor

I am building a website in Wordpress and would like to know how to underline individual items on the navigation bar. I am aware that this has been asked before but I have tried everything in the threads and it doesn't seem to work.

I am using Elementor Pro and trying to add additional CSS for the navigation bar. It seems to be staying green (which is the default color for Elementor plugin) and when I disabled this through the plugin settings all the items changed to white. When adding additional CSS to change the color, it isn't working.

Edit: I would also like this with a gap between the text and underline so would I be better using a border? How would I use this approach?

**Current CSS:**
After reading the duplicate threat, I have tried the below code:

```
.nav-list-item-322 a {
    color: #258;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
span {
    color: grey;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

It is changing the drop-down arrow colour, but nothing else.

Anyone know how to resolve this? If you need additional information please let me know!

This isn't a duplicate as I've tried everything from other threads and it isn't working.

Comment: We'll need to see some code. A [mcve] in your question please.

Comment: use `text-decoration-color` and increase your line height - if you are just wanting a bottom border then use that and padding bottom.  But please take a tour of the [help centre](http://stackoverflow.com/help) to see [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and what types of question are [on topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for the site